# How to handle exceptions when using routerLink in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a component with routerLink, and the routing module has a route.
The ngOnInit calls a service

```
this.myService.create(aId).subscribe(
data => { this.ourdata = data;
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<test>(data.some);
},
err => console.error(err),
() => console.log('Done '+ JSON.stringify(this.ourdata))
);
```

and html shows spinner till data is received

```
<div *ngif="!ourdata">
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
<div *ngif="ourdata" class="centering-div">
...
</div>
```

In case I get an exception, how can I show a dialog and stop the spinner? I am looking for change in html template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `err` callback of the subscribe.

```
error: boolean;
.....
this.myService.create(aId).subscribe(
data => { 
   this.ourdata = data;
   this.error = false;
   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<test>(data.some);
},
err => { 
   console.error(err); 
   this.error = true;
   // call method that shows the dialog
   // or show the dialog in the HTML based on the value of error being true
}
() => console.log('Done '+ JSON.stringify(this.ourdata))
);
```

```
<div *ngif="!ourdata && !error">
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
<div *ngif="ourdata" class="centering-div">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. looks like it will work. Will try this and accept answer or let you know the result. I have a dialog service, so will call open err => {...},

Comment: Yep, it works. I had a route guard, so had to handle a null pointer